# Need help w/ simple 2 number output for virtual keypad in Flash Pro CS6, yes I read the other stuff

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash

I'm used to authoring Macromedia Flash 4.0 (1999 - 2008). Lost my old version of Flash in a house fire 4 years ago, and now I'm stuck with the "improved" Adobe Flash Pro CS6, trying to help out a friend open his new restaurant.

Here's what I need:

I have a simple 12 button (the "Back" and "Next" buttons are fine) virtual numeric keypad as part of a food ordering app for his restaurant. It only needs to output 2 separate variable values to designate the table number of a customer. In doing so, I want it to execute 2 simple functions. First, any button that is clicked on should advance the timeline to the frame I've designated for that button. Second, the same mouse click should also input a single digit numeric value into a capture text/output text field. There should be one capture text/output field for each of the 2 single digit number values.

In old Flash, I could assign that very easily to each button. In this new version, it now wants all kinds of newer AS3 programming code. Which is just downright crazy. Count on Adobe to cannibalize the competition, and screw up what used to be a perfectly good product.

Please don't tell me to look at so-and-so's virtual keyboard, etc. I've already seen about 12 of them. They all suck for my purpose. If I wanted to have written this entire app in JavaScript, XML, HTML5, or whatever else... I WOULD have. But I told a friend I'd do this for him by Monday, and I don't have time to go back and re-write code for the entire app. Nor do I want to.

I SHOULD be able to just create an action layer within each button. Then assign it the actions of "goto frame X and stop", as well as "load variable X value" to output field display. But out of close to 100 searches/tutorials, I can't find a single one about a simple way to do that in FP-CS6. And that includes something like 14 different topics I've read here on StackOverFlow, that seem to regularly feature somebody named "Tres".

I already figured out the External Interface Class thing to export the variable values out of FP-CS6 into JavaScript, so that it can work with jZebra's web applet, and send raw data to a Star TSP 100/143 LAN thermal receipt printer. All being run off 2 LAN/CAT5 networked HP Pavilion TS-20s running Win-8 integrated multi-touch screens. I'm Old School, not lazy, stupid, or a dinosaur. I do know what I'm talking about.

I just can't get my head around how Adobe could have so totally screwed up what used to be such a simple thing. But then again, I always did hate Acrobat and Photoshop. Lotus and Corel were always superior.

If anyone's up to the challenge, I'd appreciate it. Meanwhile, I'll be figuring out a FUBAR work-around back-up that even Adobe can't screw up.